# How much do the blades on the V22 or AW609 weigh?

Tags: blade, v-22, tiltrotor

It seems that the blades on the V22 or AW609 would have to be heavier than conventional helicopter rotor blades since they have to be substantially stiffer when in fixed-wing mode. Normal helicopter blades would flap beyond acceptable levels when exposed to such high forward airspeed. It also appears that since tiltrotor disc loading is much higher, conventional thin helicopter blades would sag excessively.

So, how much do the blades actually weigh?

Answer (score 5):

" However, two Osprey 38-foot rotors weigh 4,654 lbs (JANE's, 1998-9, p. 557.)" this quote is from http://www.freepatentsonline.com/8382030.html

**That would put the mass of a single V22 rotor at 1050 kg**. The quoted source dates from 1998, so some improvements may have been made, but it is unclear to which parts of the rotor this refers, so it's only a guesstimate anyways.